# How to override the Authentication when calling one specific web service?

Tags: web-services, security, websphere, rad

I use a number of web services to communicate with SAP. The services were generated using a wizard in RAD. A standard login was defined in the WS Bindings of the Deployment Description.

The SAP team now want me to call one specific service using the login details of the current user and not to use the standard login. The user would be prompted to enter the login details and these would be stored in the session.

I had thought that I need to use `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler` but I can't immediately see how to access the user's session.

I could create the SOAP request by hand and set the Authentication myself but I would rather use the wizard for all services.

What is the best way to override the authentication of a web service at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/twbs_confighttpbasicauthprog.html

```
Properties prop = new Properties(); 
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(prop); 
Service service = (Service)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/service/StockQuoteService"); 
QName portQname = new QName("http://httpchannel.test.wsfvt.ws.ibm.com", "StockQuoteHttp"); 
StockQuote sq = (StockQuote)service.getPort(portQname, StockQuote.class); 
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) sq)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myUser");
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) sq)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "myPwd");
```